# How to write manual SQL command in VB.Net to Update from DataGridView without using CommandBuilder

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, datagridview, sqlcommandbuilder

I am creating a windows application using VB.Net & SQLite Database. In one of my win form i used to retrieve data from two tables (`ImpShpHeader`, `ImpShpDetail`) by separate SQL command under a single event. `ImpShpHeader` Data retrieving in textboxes while data from `ImpShpDetail` retrieving in `DataGridView` and updating both tables with button click event with two separate SQL commands one command is to update from textboxes to `ImpShpHeader` but update from `DataGridView` to `ImpshpDetail` i am using `CommandBuilder`. Update from textboxes to `ImpShpHeader` is Successful but update by `CommandBuilder` gives following error: **Dynamic SQL generation not supported for multiple base tables.** So here i need manual SQL command to update any changes in DataGridView. Here is My Code:

```
'TO RETRIEVE DATA FROM TABLES
Private Sub txtContainerNo_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtContainerNo.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Try
            con.Open()

            cmdString = "SELECT * FROM ImpShpHeader WHERE container = '" & txtContainerNo.Text & "'"
            ImpShpHeaderDA = New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmdString, con)
            ImpShpHeaderDA.Fill(ImpShpHeaderDT)

            txtContainer.Text = ImpShpHeaderDT.Rows(0).Item("container").ToString
            txtContainer.Enabled = False
            txtShipper.Text = ImpShpHeaderDT.Rows(0).Item("shipper").ToString
            txtPackages.Text = ImpShpHeaderDT.Rows(0).Item("packages").ToString
            txtETA.Text = ImpShpHeaderDT.Rows(0).Item("eta").ToString

            cmdString = "SELECT item, description, shipqty FROM ImpShpDetail WHERE container = '" & txtContainer.Text & "'"
            ImpShpDetailDA = New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmdString, con)
            ImpShpDetailDA.Fill(ImpShpDetailDT)
            dgvImpShpDetail.DataSource = ImpShpDetailDT

            'STYLE AND APPEARENCE OF DATA GRID VIEW
            dgvImpShpDetail.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Item No."
            dgvImpShpDetail.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Description"
            dgvImpShpDetail.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Ship Qty"

            dgvImpShpDetail.RowHeadersVisible = False

            dgvImpShpDetail.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells

            dgvImpShpDetail.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            dgvImpShpDetail.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
            dgvImpShpDetail.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Ann error occured!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
        End Try
        con.Close()
    End If
End Sub

'TO UPDATE MULTIPLE TABLES
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    dlgResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save the changes?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If dlgResult = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Try
            con.Open()

            cmdString = "UPDATE ImpShpHeader SET container = @container, shipper = @shipper, packages = @packages, eta = @eta WHERE container = '" & txtContainer.Text & "'"

            cmd = New SQLiteCommand(cmdString, con)

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@container", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtContainer.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@shipper", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtShipper.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@packages", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPackages.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@eta", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtETA.Text

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cmdbl = New SQLiteCommandBuilder(ImpShpDetailDA)
            ImpShpDetailDA.Update(ImpShpDetailDT)

            MsgBox("Updated successfully!")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("An error occured!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
        End Try
        con.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You used params for most things why not the WHERE clause too?  Your SQL is only updating one table, so the reason for the error is *probably*  because you replaced the DataAdapter for `ImpShpHeader`  with SQL for `ImpShpDetail` then try to update `ImpShpHeader`.

Comment: Changes in textboxes relates to `ImpShpHeader` and above SQL command to update `ImpShpHeader` works perfectly the problem is updating `ImpShpDetail` Table from DataGridView using CommandBuilder.

Comment: Look at the keypress code.  You create `ImpShpDetailDA` twice.  The last time for use with `ImpShpDetail`.  You cannot then reuse it to build SQL commands on `ImpShpHeader `.  The SQL is **not**  for more than one table, but your code has confused the data provider,  Use the debugger to look at the SelectCommand there in the click event.

Comment: Not clear, can you please send a corrected code.